# How do I create arrays within an array in C without a predefined size?

Tags: c, arrays, syntax, malloc

I would like to create arrays within an array in C without a pre-defined number of characters or input in the array.
The following is my code:

```
{
    int noOfStudents,noOfItems;
    int *grades;
    int i;
    char a[];
    printf("Please enter number of students\n");
    scanf("%d", &noOfStudents);
    printf("Please enter number of items\n");
    scanf("%d", &noOfItems);

    for (i = 0; i < noOfStudents; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (int *)malloc((sizeof(int))*noOfItems);
    }
```

I've been thrown an error

> c(2133): 'a': unknown size

How do I successfully create arrays within an array by means of malloc?

Comment: an array of what? char or int?? use `int **a = malloc(sizeof(int *)*nbOfStudents);` first. You want a bidimensional array.

Comment: @Sarah Collins  You are here about three years and till now are you so bad?:)

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of a [VLA (Variable length array)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

You need to rearrange your code like

```
int noOfStudents = -1, noOfItems = -1;
int *grades;                                //is it used?
int i;

printf("Please enter number of students\n");
scanf("%d", &noOfStudents);

//fail check

int *a[noOfStudents];             // this needs to be proper.

//VLA

printf("Please enter number of items\n");
scanf("%d", &noOfItems);

//fail check

for (i = 0; i < noOfStudents; i++)
{
    a[i] = malloc(noOfItems * sizeof(a[i]));   //do not cast
}
```

Comment: You can also use `int (*a)[noOfStudents] = malloc(sizeof *a * noOfItems);` instead of a VLA of pointers.

Comment: @mch no doubt, just another approach.

Answer (score 2):

You want a bi-dimensional array, to hold the list of lists of integer items. You can do that by declaring a pointer on integer pointers.

So you want to declare

```
int **a;
```

then

```
printf("Please enter number of students\n");
if (scanf("%d", &noOfStudents)==0 && noOfStudents<=0)  // bonus: small safety
{
    printf("input error\n");
    exit(1);
}
// now we are sure that noOfStudents is strictly positive & properly entered
a = malloc(sizeof(int*)*noOfStudents);
```

Then you have your array of pointers allocated, and the rest of your code is OK (don't cast the return value of `malloc` BTW)

A variant is:

```
a = malloc(sizeof(*a)*noOfStudents);
```

(so if type of `a` changes, the size follows, not that it matters here since they're all pointers)

Answer (score 0):

Use pointer instead of array and allocates the memory of that pointer dynamically using `malloc` or `calloc` function.

Like this:

```
int *a;

a = malloc((sizeof(int)*noOfItems);
```

Answer (score -2):

You may try the function `malloc`, which dynamically allocates memory and returns a pointer to it. Then you can cast the pointer to a pointer pointing to an array of a certain type.

Comment: Never heard of `mallocate`

Comment: Either update the answer or remove it, it's no good to anyone. To best, it is misleading and not helpful.

Comment: sorry, that's a typo